# Scale SVG to fill 90% of available space (while maintaining aspect ratio)

Tags: css, svg

I have a `<div id="Frame">` element, within it is a `<svg>` element. I would like the `<svg>` element to be centered in the frame, and grow at a aspect ratio of 1/1, until one edge uses up say 90% of the available space (so it almost fills the whole space, but has a bit of a border).
But I can't get the SVG to grow. I read the many other similar SO answers, some say CSS overrides the width/height attributes of the SVG, but I tried removing them just incase (not ideal), but it still did not grow). The other common soluation is `width: 100%; height: auto;`, which did not work for me.

```css
main {
  padding: 0; margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  }
  
#FRAME {
  padding: 0; margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  position:relative;
}

#FRAME svg {
  max-width: 90%;
  max-height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="FRAME">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" width="24">
      <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
      <path d="M3 5v14a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2H5a2 2 0 0 0-2 2zm12 4c0 1.66-1.34 3-3 3s-3-1.34-3-3 1.34-3 3-3 3 1.34 3 3zm-9 8c0-2 4-3.1 6-3.1s6 1.1 6 3.1v1H6v-1z"></path>
    </svg>
  </div>
 </main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a [`viewBox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) to the SVG to determine the SVG viewport.

Whilst the `width` and `height` attributes help with keeping the aspect ratio, `viewBox` helps with scaling the SVG contents correctly.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" width="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
  <path d="M3 5v14a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2H5a2 2 0 0 0-2 2zm12 4c0 1.66-1.34 3-3 3s-3-1.34-3-3 1.34-3 3-3 3 1.34 3 3zm-9 8c0-2 4-3.1 6-3.1s6 1.1 6 3.1v1H6v-1z"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you! Nothing was working without it. I used a SVG optimizer, and it removed it.

Comment: Here is the relevant Issue on GitHub [svg/svgo #1128](https://github.com/svg/svgo/issues/1128). At the time of writing its open since 07.2019. Fun read …